# No puedo conectarme desde .NET a SQL

Tags: sql, .net

ya cree el usuario en la base de datos, con los permisos de sysadmin, y dbowner para la base de datos.

Cuando se conecta desde .NET, se produce el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: 2]

así tengo el webconfig:

```
<add name="PruebaTecnicaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PruebaTecnicaModel.csdl|res://*/PruebaTecnicaModel.ssdl|res://*/PruebaTecnicaModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=Doctus.PruebaTecnica;User Id=usrPruebaTecnica;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

También intenté agregar directamente desde la cadena de conexión pero tampoco funciona, pero eliminando la seguridad integrada

Ahora modifique el IIS: identity = LocalSystem

También moví otras cosas del IIS pero nada permanece desconectado. He estado tratando de resolver este problema todo el día y nada

Comment: Y en tu BD ¿tienes habilitado el acceso mediante `Autenticación de SQL`? Porque si solo lo tienes para acceder únicamente mediante `Autenticación de Windows`, nunca vas a poder acceder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa que el usuario con el que estás intentando conectarte a SQL, tenga seleccionada la opción conectar SQL, dentro de la opción, elementos protegibles, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esa fue la solución!. gracias un saludo!